# Why won't my batch finish?

Tags: 8, batch-operations

I have setup a Batch work which looks the following (dump at run time).

[image]

The method called for each batch is a public static method, so that is not a problem.

All operations performs perfectly, my nodes are imported in the system, this I'm sure.

The problem is that the Batch progress bar never reaches the 100% and after a few seconds, goes back and forth forever. This clearly happens after all my nodes are processed.

My *finished* callback is never called and I'm stuck on the Batch API progress bar for years :-)

Any idea on what I could be missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, nothing was wrong with my batch definition, but I tried to disable the web profiler module and everything gets back to normal!

Comment: But I have this same problem, and I don't have the web profiler module installed... Do you know why that module was causing this...?